trouble working with Events that have an onlineMeeting
I generate the onlinemeeting first using the online meetings endpoint.
Later when posting the event I try to attach this meeting:
isOnlineMeeting is set to true and even though I use setOnlineMeeting to set the MeetingInfo which includes the JoinUrl plus I set the url with setOnlineMeetingUrl (don't really understand this redundancy) as a consequence this is unfortunately ignored and new meeting (url) is generated when posting the event.
I tried to work around this by not using the onlinemeeting endpoint but by generating the onlinemeeting in the first place by actually posting the Event with just setIsOnlineMeeting to true and using the returned generated url. So far so good.
But then when updating the event, to prevent a new meeting being generated again because my data is ignored, I completely ommit any onlinemeeting stuff in the body so it should not be changed, like when I ommit a subject. isOnlineMeeting is neither true nor false.
But the updated event then has isOnlineMeeting set to false, having lost any onlinemeeting information.
Really at my wits end here.
And by the way the conferenceId is also ignored, even when fetching the whole event, but I hope I don't need this.

If you are patching a meeting via the Event endpoint what properties are you actually trying to update? You shouldn't be modifying any of the online meeting setting via this endpoint because they won't be synced back if you want to modify the conference you would need to then use the online meeting endpoint.  To rule in/out a bug somewhere try a simple reproduction in the Graph Explorer and post the result of that, it generally paints a much clearer picture of what may be happening.

but as I wrote, patching any event that has/is an onlinemeeting will either result in creation of a completely new meeting url if I use "isOnlineMeeting" plus any or none of the related props, or completely remove the onlinemeeting from the event if I ommit all onlinemeeting related props.

Also Events with Meetings originating from Outlook present themself to me as "Events" with isOnlineMeeting with onlinemeeting->joinUrl. Why would patching an event in the same exact form not work? Are you saying I need to patch them as OnlineMeeting?

", patching any event that has/is an onlinemeeting will either result in creation of a completely new meeting url if I use "isOnlineMeeting", This shouldn't happen and it not what I see if I do the same thing, so it maybe associated with the particular way you doing it that is caused by a bug. Or the code you using isn't doing what you expect, it should be pretty easy to test in the Graph Explorer. In the Events endpoint you should treat all the online meeting properties as readonly once created. Remember that they are different datastores with sync between them.

It appears that the link must be contained in the body aswell, or else they'll screw it up. Way to go, MS.
